# Run nvm with docker exec

Tags: docker, gitlab-ci

I want to run nvm with `docker exec`

something like

```
docker run -d <image>
docker exec <container> nvm use v6.13.0 && npm install
```

but I have an error

```
OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:296: starting container process caused "exec: \"nvm\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown
```

I know that I can do something like that which work

```
docker exec <container> /bin/bash -c 'source "$NVM_DIR"/nvm.sh && nvm use v6.13.0'
```

But I don't want. Why ? because the point is to create a docker container usable with all my project with different version of python and node and run the `nvm use <version> &&  npm install` directly from gitlab-ci using the `.nvmrc` file into my project

my gitlab-cy.yml run a makefile which basically run the nvm use and npm install

```
image: cracky5457/nvm-pyenv-yarn

stages:
  - install
  - test

variables:
  GITLAB_CACHING: "true"

cache:
  paths:
    - pip-cache/
  key: "python_2.7"

installing:
  stage: install
  script:
    - make install
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - venv/
      - node_modules/
    expire_in: 1 hour
  tags:
    - docker-runner
```

and I don't want to push `/bin/bash -c` into my makefile because the project will become docker dependent locally

This is my docker image with the instructions to run it ( you have to create a file base_dependencies.txt, node-versions.txt, python-versions.txt ) or you can just `docker pull cracky5457/nvm-pyenv-yarn`

https://hub.docker.com/r/cracky5457/nvm-pyenv-yarn/

```
FROM phusion/baseimage:0.10.0

 # Make sure bash is the standard shell
RUN rm /bin/sh && ln -sf /bin/bash /bin/sh

ENV ENV ~/.profile
ENV PYENV_ROOT /root/.pyenv
ENV PATH $PYENV_ROOT/shims:$PYENV_ROOT/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:$PATH

# Add yarn registry
RUN curl -sS https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | apt-key add - && \
    echo "deb https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/ stable main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list

# Install base system libraries.
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
COPY base_dependencies.txt /base_dependencies.txt
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y $(cat /base_dependencies.txt)

# Install pyenv and default python version.
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE true
RUN git clone https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv.git /root/.pyenv && \
    cd /root/.pyenv && \
    git checkout `git describe --abbrev=0 --tags` && \
    eval "$(pyenv init -)"

# Install nvm and default node version.
ENV NVM_DIR /usr/local/nvm
RUN curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.33.8/install.sh | bash && \
    echo 'source $NVM_DIR/nvm.sh' >> /etc/profile

# Clean up APT when done.
RUN apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*

# Install python and node versions
COPY python-versions.txt /python-versions.txt
RUN for version in $(cat python-versions.txt); do pyenv install $version; pyenv global $version; pip install virtualenv; done
COPY node-versions.txt /node-versions.txt
RUN for version in $(cat node-versions.txt); do source $NVM_DIR/nvm.sh; nvm install $version; done

# Use baseimage-docker's init system.
CMD ["/sbin/my_init"]
```

Answer (score 1):

I didn't found a proper way.

You can create a bash file into `/usr/bin/nvm` with `chmod +x /usr/bin/nvm`

```
#!/bin/bash

export NVM_DIR="/usr/local/nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion"  # This loads nvm bash_completion

nvm "$@"
```

And then

```
docker exec <container> nvm use
```

But it's tricky and I can't add an other instruction in my exec, for exemple I can't `docker exec <container> nvm use && npm install` at the same time.

But I finally fixed my issue directly in `gitlab-ci.yaml` using

```
 $(NVM_DIR)/nvm.sh && nvm use && npm install
```